# How to read signed bytes from a file

Tags: c#, io

I got a file with lines of hex words.

Basically, I want to read the file into an array `sbyte[]`.

I know probably I can read it into a `byte[]` using

```
byte[] bt = File.ReadAllBytes("fileName");
```

But how to read it into a signed byte array?
Could somebody give me some ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How big is the file? If it is small enough that `File.ReadAllBytes` is fine, you can probably just do:

```
byte[] bt = File.ReadAllBytes("fileName");
sbyte[] sbt = new sbyte[bt.Length];
Buffer.BlockCopy(bt, 0, sbt, 0, bt.Length);
```

Although frankly: I'd keep it as a `byte[]` and worry about signed/unsigned elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The size of the file is around 4000 kb. It's a small file as you can see. About the BlockCopy method, could I also use it to move the data from a float[] into a sbyte[], like var byteArray = new byte[data.Length * 4];
                Buffer.BlockCopy(data, 0, byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);

Comment: @user3535716 yes, but when handling multi-byte data you need to be aware of endianness.

Answer (score 3):

You can just cast the bytes:

```
byte[] bt = File.ReadAllBytes("fileName");
sbyte[] sbytes = Array.ConvertAll(bt, b => (sbyte)b);
```

Or if you prefer to read the file directly as `sbyte`s, you can do something like that:

```
static IEnumerable<sbyte> ReadSBytes(string path)
{
    using (var stream = File.OpenRead(path))
    using (var reader = new BinaryReader(stream))
    {
        while (true)
        {
            sbyte sb;
            try
            {
                sb = reader.ReadSByte();
            }
            catch(EndOfStreamException)
            {
                break;
            }
            yield return sb;
        }
    }
}

sbyte[] sbytes = ReadSBytes("fileName").ToArray();
```

Comment: Is `return sb;` meant to be `yield return sb;`?

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko, yes, that was my intent... I fixed it, thanks!